# Express Js - Connecting to MongoDB database on demand

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on an application that needs to connect to different MongoDB databases based on the customer that is accessing my application. Each MongoDB database is located on separate servers.

For example, if my application has 3 different customers:

- john (mongodb://john:john@server1/john)
- tom (mongodb://tom:tom@server2/tom)
- harry (mongodb://harry:harry@server3/harry)

when john uses my application, Express.js should connect to `mongodb://john:john@server1/john` or when harry uses my application, it should connect to `mongodb://harry:harry@server3/harry`.

I am wondering what an optimized way would be to achieve this. Normally, when we have just one MongoDB database instance, we put the `mongoose.connect` method inside the `app.js` and that gets called when the Express.js server starts, but in this case I don't want to connect all three databases at once since that will not be the optimized way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections), it does support connections to multiple hosts.

```js
const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection('host1', options)
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('host2', options)
```

Let me give you an example (this is Express code) :

```js
// CONNECTION SETTER MIDDLEWARE
app.use(async function (req, res, next) {
    // Let's just assume you identified the user earlier with your favourite 
    // auth method and put their identity in req.user
    const userCon = await mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://${req.user.username}:${req.user.password}@${req.user.host}/${req.user.database}`) // Here you have it!
    // Saving the connection in the request so the next 
    // middlewares/handlers can access it
    req.user.connection = userCon
    // Thank you, next (middleware/handler)
    next()
});
```

While `mongoose.connect()` sets the default connection, `mongoose.createConnection()` only returns a connection.

This is what I would try, and this is Mongoose's recommended way to handle multiple connections. You should note that you can't share Models across different connections, but you can share Schemas.

If you want to just initialize the connection and connect later, the Mongoose docs also provide [an example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-createConnection).

```js
// initialize now, connect later
db = mongoose.createConnection();
db.openUri('localhost', 'database', port, [opts]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. What happens if two user access the application at the same time? will there be a conflict in req.user.connection between those user's mongodb connection string?

Comment: There's absolutely no chance to have an issue with `req`. Each request has its own `req` object. Otherwise, servers that receive multiple requests at the same time would randomly answer, but not to the right client.

Comment: i see, Is this behaviour the same if i store the connection in global.connection instead of req.connection?

Comment: Storing something in `global` is a bad idea, but most importantly this is completely useless: every connection is proper to the request and its user, not to the process. Storing data about the user/request in `req` is a common practice. `req` is the only var that can be changed and that's passed between all middleware natively by Express, therefore it is the only right place to store this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Appreciate it.